# How to rotate a vertex group?

Tags: mesh

Edit Mode
Is it possible to rotate a vertex group around the 3D cursor or some other fixed point on the mesh?

Thank you kindly.

Comment: You need to choose the 3D cursor in the Transform Pivot Point panel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *Hook* modifier can make another object (an Empty, here) grab a targeted vertex-group, and give the group its own transform, by weight.

[image]

A `0` 'Falloff' radius is infinite.

Comment: Thank you Robin, must I make another object in order to rotate a vertex group. Please forgive my ignorance, but my logic comes from the CAD solid modeling world. I would like to keep the mesh intact, I thought I could position the 3d cursor where I would like to rotate the vertex group, and simply enter a degree value. Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: (You can parent the empty to the deformed object, so you can fire and forget, .. but yes, this way, you still have to create it.) I, too, am frustrated by this: see my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/220159/35559). IMO, it would absolutely have been consistent with Blender's philosophy of providing foundational tools to have had a _Simple Transform_ modifier from the get-go, from which you could assemble a wide variety of other 'modifiers', yourself. If there's nothing in the immediate future of Geometry Nodes to make it easier, I'll start making my own groups, there.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to answer my own question after learning about the *Transform Pivot Point Options*.

[image]

Comment: Ahhh... OK, I thought you needed the _weights_ in the group, not just the selection.