# Transform Mesh from Vertex Groups with Geometry Nodes

Tags: mesh, transforms, geometry-nodes, vertex-groups

How I can rotate the selected geometry 90º using geometry Nodes?

[image]

[image]

I created a vertex group with the selection above named "Group" but I can't figure out how to transform / rotate the mesh only within the selected attribute.

The result seems very far from the original **X axis**.

Comment: and why do you want to rotate this with geometry nodes? from the information you gave geometry nodes makes no sense here at all...

Comment: You might check out my answer to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220159/geometry-nodes-rotate-positions-about-a-point?rq=1, which demonstrates a vertex-group limited transform of a mesh via GN.  I believe that's in 2.93.1.  Basically, you transform everything, then you lerp between the original mesh and your new mesh by your VG.

Comment: Thanks Nathan! I saw it long before posting, but tbh... It's overkill,
as a proof of design, Houdini allows for this basic translation from default, which is necessary for any serious procedural modeling. This is something that should be hard coded IMO. Now with Fields the transform node could benefit from a "selection" input, we just need a brave developer to figure handling multiple arbitrary origins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do it :

- [Separate Geometry](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/separate_geometry.html) by the input group that you'll set in the modifier properties.
- [Transform](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/transform.html) the selected geometry
- [Join](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/join_geometry.html) both geometries

[image]

[image]

Note the rotation is set relatively to the local $0, 0, 0$ origin. If you want to rotate from another point in space, you'll have to use [fancy vector maths](https://answers.unity.com/questions/532297/rotate-a-vector-around-a-certain-point.html).

Answer (score 0):

i think there is a misunderstanding here.

The attribute vector rotate node has an input "vector", not "vector group". You cannot fill in a vector group in an input which expects a vector.

And adding position to rotation vector...makes no sense either.

Maybe it is a good idea to watch some very basic tutorials about vectors and math.

Comment: No, I want to be able to rotate parts of my mesh based on my vertex group selection. This offers extra manipulation that's not currently possible with shape keys, as well as keeping everything within one object for data structure.