# Combine multiple pipes in node viewer

Tags: node-editor

I have seen multiple times in the node editor that you can split a noodle/pipe, with a socket in the middle of what would otherwise be a normal pipe. I have found no documentation or any other information on this, but I know it is possible, such as seen from the image from [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220159/geometry-nodes-rotate-positions-about-a-point):

[image: Image showing the split noodle as described above]

What is the keyboard shortcut or method of performing this split?

(Bonus: Is there a specific, official name for the noodles/pipes?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create those handy little things by holding down shift and right click, then sweeping over a connection line. They're called "Reroute Nodes". Here's some more documentation if you're interested: [Blender 3.4 Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/nodes/reroute.html)

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: doesn't this require to enable the Node Wrangler addon first?

Comment: @L0Lock For this you don't need it, it's built in.

Comment: That's interesting, I thought that was node wrangler.  Cut with ctrl + right click is default too, or no?

Comment: Also, if you already have the noodles connected, you can sweep over all the noodles from the same source and it will merge them all into a reroute